# Elasticsearch: Query an array element

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I create a query to search for "TV antenna" in Elasticsearch that would return only the first object?

```
{
    "name": "First",
    "categories": ["Medium TV antennas and cables", "TV cables"]
},
{
    "name": "Second",
    "categories": ["antennas and cables", "TV and accessories"]
}
```

Could anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/indexxx/topic/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "categories": {
        "query": "TV antenna",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a phrase match query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "categories": {
                "query": "TV antennas"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html